# JPA User, Role, manyToMany hibernate relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA+Hibernate+SpringBoot+PostgreSQL, to create a relationship between different entities, but I am getting a ton of errors, including what looks like SQL errors, but the application started up anyway. Did I code the manyToMany relation correctly? There could be many users, and each user can have multiple roles. Maybe OneToMany is better?

I'm using "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"

These are the only hibernate files I have so far.

**Role.java**

```
@Entity(name = "role")
public class Role implements java.io.Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5525359165179861924L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    int id;

    private String role;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> users;


    public Role(String role) {
        super();
        this.role = role;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUser(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4910225916550731448L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created")
    Date created;

    @Column(name = "firstName", length = 100)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName", length = 100)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email", length = 150)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "username", length = 150)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private int enabled;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleId", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    protected User(){
        roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles(){
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles){
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String username, Set<Role> roles) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

And the errors I get:

```
2017-04-24 22:49:19.163  WARN 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.
2017-04-24 22:49:19.167  WARN 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.
2017-04-24 22:49:19.438  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator     : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.example.domain.Role (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2017-04-24 22:49:19.527  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: alter table user_roles drop constraint FKrhfovtciq1l558cw6udg0h0d3
2017-04-24 22:49:19.531 ERROR 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user_roles drop constraint FKrhfovtciq1l558cw6udg0h0d3
2017-04-24 22:49:19.531 ERROR 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: relation "user_roles" does not exist
Hibernate: alter table user_roles drop constraint FK55itppkw3i07do3h7qoclqd4k
2017-04-24 22:49:19.532 ERROR 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user_roles drop constraint FK55itppkw3i07do3h7qoclqd4k
2017-04-24 22:49:19.533 ERROR 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: relation "user_roles" does not exist
Hibernate: drop table if exists role cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists user cascade
2017-04-24 22:49:19.535 ERROR 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table if exists user cascade
2017-04-24 22:49:19.535 ERROR 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 22
Hibernate: drop table if exists user_roles cascade
Hibernate: drop sequence hibernate_sequence
2017-04-24 22:49:19.537 ERROR 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop sequence hibernate_sequence
2017-04-24 22:49:19.538 ERROR 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: sequence "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start 1 increment 1
Hibernate: create table role (id int4 not null, role varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table user (id int8 not null, created timestamp, email varchar(150), enabled int4, first_name varchar(100), last_name varchar(100), username varchar(150), primary key (id))
2017-04-24 22:49:19.564 ERROR 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table user (id int8 not null, created timestamp, email varchar(150), enabled int4, first_name varchar(100), last_name varchar(100), username varchar(150), primary key (id))
2017-04-24 22:49:19.564 ERROR 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 14
Hibernate: create table user_roles (user_id int8 not null, role_id int4 not null, primary key (user_id, role_id))
Hibernate: alter table user_roles add constraint FKrhfovtciq1l558cw6udg0h0d3 foreign key (role_id) references role
Hibernate: alter table user_roles add constraint FK55itppkw3i07do3h7qoclqd4k foreign key (user_id) references user
2017-04-24 22:49:19.585 ERROR 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user_roles add constraint FK55itppkw3i07do3h7qoclqd4k foreign key (user_id) references user
2017-04-24 22:49:19.585 ERROR 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
  Position: 100
2017-04-24 22:49:19.585  INFO 20488 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Comment: `user` is the key word . you cannot use that name as your table name .

Comment: Use backticks to escape the table name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you should drop your database or change your hibernate config to create

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

and the error is

```
ERROR: relation "user_roles" does not exist
```

so you should name the ManyToMany as **user_roles**:

```
@JoinTable(name="user_roles",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    )
    private List<Role> roles;
```

in My project User  Entity is :

```
  @Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends AbstractPersistable<Long>{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Column(name = "USER_NAME", unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;



    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    )
    private List<Role> roles;



    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }



    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }



    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }



    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }



    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }



    public User(String username, String password, List<Role> roles) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }



    public User() {
        super();
    }
}
```

and Roles :

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String role;

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

Comment: How come you don't have Id stuff in your files? also you don't implement serializable but you extend AbstractPersistable<Long> ?

Comment: the auto Generated Id is extended from AbstractPersistable , and AbstractPersistable implements Serializable

Comment: Still having some issues with adding roles detached entity persistence problem when I try to add one existing role, and one non-existing role. But maybe I should change this to OneToMany

Comment: In the case of oneToMany you dont need the joinTable

Comment: Yes true. I got rid of it just for testing. But both your code and OneToMany works. The issue I was having was persist-vs-merge and if you try to make a "new" User and new Role as well as an existing Role, and try to Cascade.ALL, it causes persist issues. Thx for help.

Comment: For those wondering why he didn't need to implement `Serializable` in the `Roles` table despite using `AbstractPersistable<Long>` it's because `Long` implements `Serializable`